# BufferReader populating 2D array missing last line

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, bufferedreader

I'm trying to use BufferReader to populate a 2D array and it successfully populates all of the rows of the array except one, the very last one. I've tried increasing the loop by one to account for that line, but I get an index out of bounds error. How can I get that last line to display?

```
public static void  inputArray(char[][] outArray, String filename) {
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    for(int i = 0; i < outArray.length; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < outArray[0].length; j++){
        outArray[i][j] = (char)br.read();
       }
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error opening the file");
}
}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
```

File contents:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yzab
```

Here's the code I use to print out the array:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < test[0].length; j++) {
          System.out.printf("%1c",test[i][j]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Post the file contents so we can see what the array is missing.

Comment: How big is `outArray`? Also, how do you expect to handle newlines?

Comment: outArray was [7][4], I'm not sure what you mean by handle newlines?

Comment: @BenjiFrank your file contains `a`, then `b`, then `c`, then `d`, then a newline, then `e`, then `f`, then `g`, then `h`, then a newline, then `i`, then `j`, ...etc

Comment: Also, have you tried using a debugger to find out the problem?

Comment: You're filling `outArray` but printing out `test`. Strange.

Comment: @immibis@Ravi So my array is storing a character for a new line? How should I go about handling this?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I'm filling outArray inside of a method, and calling that method in my main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the newlines in the array.

Given that code, and that file, and that `outArray` contains [7][4] elements, `outArray` should end up containing:

```
outArray[0][0] == 'a'
outArray[0][1] == 'b'
outArray[0][2] == 'c'
outArray[0][3] == 'd'
outArray[1][0] == '\n'
outArray[1][1] == 'e'
outArray[1][2] == 'f'
outArray[1][3] == 'g'
outArray[2][0] == 'h'
outArray[2][1] == '\n'
outArray[2][2] == 'i'
outArray[2][3] == 'j'
// etc
outArray[6][0] == '\n'
outArray[6][1] == 'u'
outArray[6][2] == 'v'
outArray[6][3] == 'w'
```

or in table form:

```
    0    1    2    3
0  'a'  'b'  'c'  'd'
1 '\n'  'e'  'f'  'g'
2  'h' '\n'  'i'  'j'
3  'k'  'l' '\n'  'm'
4  'n'  'o'  'p' '\n'
5  'q'  'r'  's'  't'
6 '\n'  'u'  'v'  'w'
```

This is because you are ignoring the fact that your file also contains newline characters. If your file didn't contain any newline characters (i.e. it was all on one line) then your code would successfully read it into the 7x4 array.

If your file always has the same format, you could skip over the newlines (since you know where to expect them), like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < outArray.length; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < outArray[0].length; j++){
    outArray[i][j] = (char)br.read();
   }
   br.read(); // read the next character (which will be a newline) and ignore it
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realize that I was storing `'\n'`, and my lack of a `System.out.println();` in the output code made my error harder for me to see.

Answer (score 0):

I see Immebis has already supplied a great answer. Here's some code I was writing for you in the mean time.

I always try to avoid presuming the contents of a file. This may look a bit more daunting, but it enables you to focus on your intent (arrays of length 4) without needing to worry about how many you need to cater to. (What if the file contents add another character, or remove one... or become a novel?)

```
    String filename = "testData.txt";
    final int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    List<char[]> data = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        int characterIndex = 0;
        char[] nextRow = null;
        int charValue = 0;

        // You don't have to know how many characters are in the input file, in advance
        while((charValue = br.read()) != -1)
        {
            char c = (char)charValue;

            // Discard newlines
            if(c == '\n' || c == '\r')
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(characterIndex % ARRAY_SIZE == 0)
            {
                nextRow = new char[ARRAY_SIZE];
                data.add(nextRow);
                characterIndex = 0;
            }

            nextRow[characterIndex++] = c;
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file");
    }
```

Some code to iterate through the resulting List:

```
    int rowIndex = 0;
    for(char[] row : data)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("array[" + rowIndex + "][" + i + "] - " + row[i]);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
```

All the best,

Luke

Comment: This is an equally good answer, but it utilizes arraylists. I agree that arraylists are much better to use, but the task assigned required a 2D array. Thank you for the answer!